# Некорректное меню

Tags: wordpress

Небольшая проблемка..
В меню есть пункт «услуги», если нажать, то появляется «наши преимущества», а нужно, чтобы появлялись «услуги» — как исправить?

Страница, с которой нужна помощь: http://new.gelios-pnz.ru

Comment: При нажатии на "Услуги" скролит к секции "Наши услуги", в чем проблема?

Comment: В кеше браузера, вангую )

Comment: почистила кэш, проблемас осталась

Comment: зашла через другой браузер, тоже самое
нажимаю на услуги, а кидает меня на "наши преимущества"

Comment: Вы, видимо, живёте в другом Интернете. На вашей странице слова "преимущества" просто нет.

Comment: нуууу, зашла с другого компьютера, скроллинг все равно работает неправильно и есть блок "наши преимущества", сразу вниз после картинки

Comment: попробуйте у себя очистить кэш, потому что кто мои знакомые заходит, кнопка скролит на "наши преимущества"